# Spring boot como associar duas entidades

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Estou com uma duvida de como associar duas entidades utilizando o spring data + spring boot.

Tenho os dois relacionamentos:

```
@Entity(name = "profiles")
class Profile(
        @field:Id
        @field:GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Long?,

        @field:NotNull
        @field:Size(min = 5, max = 50)
        var name: String?,

        @field:NotNull
        @field:Column(unique = true)
        @field:Size(max = 120)
        var contactEmail: String?,

        @field:NotNull
        @field:Column(unique = true) @Size(max = 15)
        var contactCellphone: String?,

        @field:Column(nullable = false)
        var createdAt: Date?,

        @field:Column(nullable = false)
        var updatedAt: Date?,

        @JsonIgnore()
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "profile", cascade = arrayOf(CascadeType.ALL), fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        var debits: List = emptyList()
) {
    @PrePersist
    fun prePersist() {
        this.createdAt = Date();
        this.updatedAt = Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    fun preUpdate() {
        this.updatedAt = Date()
    }
}
```

```
@Entity(name = "debits")
data class Debit(
        @field:Id
        @field:GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        val id: Long?,

        @field:NotNull
        @field:Digits(integer = 5, fraction = 2)
        @field:Min(1)
        var debits: BigDecimal?,

        @field:NotNull
        @field:Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        var status: DebitStatus = DebitStatus.OPENED,

        @field:Column(nullable = false)
        var createdAt: Date?,

        @field:Column(nullable = false)
        var updatedAt: Date?,

        @JsonIgnore()
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id", nullable = false)
        val profile: Profile? = null,

        @JsonIgnore()
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "notification_rule_id")
        val notificationRule: NotificationRule? = null
) {
    @PrePersist
    fun prePersist() {
        this.createdAt = Date();
        this.updatedAt = Date();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    fun preUpdate() {
        this.updatedAt = Date()
    }
}

enum class DebitStatus {
    OPENED, CLOSED, DISABLED
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/debits")
class DebitController {
    @Autowired
    private val repository: DebitRepository? = null

    @GetMapping
    fun index(): List {
        return repository!!.findAll().toList()
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    fun show(@PathVariable("id") debit: Debit): Debit {
        return debit;
    }

    @PostMapping
    fun create(@Valid @RequestBody debit: Debit?): Debit {
        return repository!!.save(debit!!)
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    fun update(@PathVariable(value = "id") debit: Debit, @Valid @RequestBody newDebit: Debit): Debit {
        debit.apply {
            this.debits = newDebit.debits ?: this.debits
            this.status = newDebit.status ?: this.status
        }

        return repository!!.save(debit)
    }
}
```

Depois de criar o **profile** eu estou tentando criar o debito já associando o debito em um profile já existente. Porém da um erro:

```
{
    "debits": 100.39,
    "profile": 1
}
```

E o erro:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-06-21T18:05:43.316+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "Caused by: [... um monte de log inútil pra sua pergunta], org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column \"PROFILE_ID\"; SQL statement:insert into debits (id, created_at, debits, notification_rule_id, profile_id, status, updated_at) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-200]",
    "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement",
    "path": "/debits"
}
```

Existe a possibilidade de criar e já associar um entidade na outra? Se tiver como posso fazer utilizando o spring??

Comment: Se entendi sua dúvida, não creio que você consiga automaticamente. Você terá, via construtor ou setter mesmo, que informar à entidade `Debit` qual o `Profile` associado, buscando-o na base de dados e então passando-o à entidade `Debit`. Ah, da próxima vez, dá uma editada naquela _stacktrace_. 99% dela é inútil pro seu problema. Ajude-nos a te ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O jeito que consegui fazer foi adicionar a annotation @JsonManagedReference no relacionamento e com isso funcionou tranquilamente.